# Reset model parameters and weights of a network [pytorch] for cross-validation

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to implement 5-fold cross validation on my training.  Every fold, I need to reset the parameters of the model. I have the following code added before a certain fold is trained:

```
for i, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(kf.split(trainset)):
   for layer in model.children():
       if hasattr(layer, 'reset_parameters'):
           layer.reset_parameters()
```

Each fold is ran with 5 epochs each.  Observing the results, we have:

```
Fold 1
Best valid accuracy: 0.806000
Fold 2
Best valid accuracy: 0.852000
Fold 3
Best valid accuracy: 0.930900
```

The accuracy is increasing which means that the model was not re-initialized after training one fold.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: simply instantiate a new instance of your model in each round!

Comment: Right, thank you Rika. <3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you reset model params is the best. You loop through `model.children()` layers but may be those layers have itself children and so on.

I think the best way to reset model params is to use an init function; something like this:

```py
def init_weights(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Embedding):
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.1) ## or simply use your layer.reset_parameters()
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight, mean=0.0, std=np.sqrt(1 / m.in_features))
        if m.bias is not None: 
            nn.init.zeros_(m.bias)
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv1d):
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight, mean=0.0, std=np.sqrt(4 / m.in_channels))
        if m.bias is not None: 
            nn.init.zeros_(m.bias)
```

And then apply the function to the model:

````py
model.apply(init_weights)
```

By this way, you scan all layers in your model.
````